# Qu'est-ce qui est le plus commun: « j'ai été à Paris » ou « je suis allé à Paris » ?

Tags: niveau-de-langue

Je sais que c'est un peu informel dire  « j'ai été à Paris » (pour dire « je suis allé à Paris » ), mais je ne sais pas si c'est commun ou si ce n'est pas commun. (Je sais que la phrase  « j'ai été à Paris » a un sens different comme le passé composé de  « je suis à Paris », mais je pense que on peut l'utiliser aussi pour « je suis allé à Paris », non ?)

Pour exemple, le [wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/on) dit que les francophones disent « on » 99% des cas et « nous » seulement 1% des cas. C'est la même pour « j'ai été à Paris » et « je suis allé à Paris »?

Comment: Et le touriste collectionneur dirait: _J'ai fait Paris_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C'est très fréquent de dire « j'ai été » au lieu de « je suis allé » pour exprimer un déplacement mais c'est considéré comme du langage familier. C'est à dire qu'un enseignant français corrigeant la copie d'un élève le soulignera. Dans la conversation de tous les jours je doute qu'on y fasse beaucoup attention, du moins en dehors des lieux où il faut manier la belle langue.

Je suis allée voir ce qu'en disait [le Projet Voltaire](http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/%C2%AB-j%E2%80%99ai-ete-%C2%BB-ou-%C2%AB-je-suis-alle-%C2%BB) car bien sûr, ici, nous sommes censés donner l'exemple à ceux qui viennent apprendre notre belle langue.

J'ai fait une recherche avec Google Ngram Viewer qui m'a dit que « j'ai été à » était plus fréquent au début du 20<sup>ème</sup> siècle et « je suis allé à » plus fréquent dans la deuxième moitié du 20<sup>ème</sup> siècle.

[image: ngrams]

Answer (score 4):

Il y a une légère nuance entre les deux expressions. Le point de vue historique du *Dictionnaire raisonné des difficultés grammaticales et littéraires de la langue française* (J.-CH. Laveaux, 1847):

> Mais quelquefois on veut seulement exprimer l'existence passée d'un sujet dans un lieu, abstraction faite du mouvement par lequel il a été transporté dans ce lieu ; et alors on dit *j'ai été à Paris*, *j'ai été à Rome* ; ce qui ne signifie autre chose que j'ai existé, j'ai été présent à Paris, à Rome, et je n'y existe plus, je n'y suis plus présent. Un homme qui s'est transporté de Paris à Rome pourra bien dire je suis allé à Rome, ce qui signifiera, j'ai fait le voyage de Paris à Rome. […] À la vérité ce temps a un rapport de conséquence avec le verbe *aller* ; car pour *avoir été* en un lieu, il faut y *être allé*. Mais il n'indique en aucune manière l'idée de mouvement qui est essentielle au verbe *aller*. Il ne l'indique pas plus que *j'étais*, dans *j'étais à Rome*. Montesquieu a dit: *Strabon, malgré le témoignage d'Apollodore, parait douter que les rois grecs soient allés plus loin que Séleucus et Alexandre* ; *soient allés* indique évidemement un sens d'espace parcouru, et par conséquent de mouvement. Il ajoute : *Quand il serait vrai qu'ils n'auraient pas été plus loin, vers l'Orient, que Séleucus*. *Auraient été* indique ici la présence, l'existence en un lieu.

Suivent plusieurs exemples, pour lesquels il est expliqué que l'emploi de « j'ai été » est fautif car se « se rendre » est le sens attendu. Et une remarque intéressante, car on emploie dans la langue littéraire *être* pour une idée de mouvement dans des tournures comme :

> J'ai été le trouver.

Comment: C'est pas plutôt le REtrouver?

Comment: @Knu. [Non](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A9t%C3%A9+le+trouver%2C%C3%A9t%C3%A9+le+retrouver&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20le%20trouver%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A9t%C3%A9%20le%20retrouver%3B%2Cc0), en général c'est employé avec des actions fermes ou autoritaires. *J'ai été le retrouver* ça me parait relever d'une mauvaise maitrise de la langue.

Comment: Je ne vois pas le rapport oO Tout dépend de ce que tu voulais dire. Si tu utilises trouver on s'attend à une suite genre *pour etc*. Alors qu'avec retrouver ça sonne juste suivi d'un point.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] mais je pense que on peut l'utiliser [« j'ai été à Paris »]
>   aussi pour « je suis allé à Paris », non ?

Pour poursuivre la réflexion des réponses précédentes, en effet, les deux formules sont synonymes : « *Moi aussi je suis allé là où vous avez été. J'assistais à cette fête extraordinaire.* » (Alain-Fournier) Le fait que la première soit qualifiée d'usage plus soigné que la deuxième, plus familière, pourrait nous faire croire que c'est le choix entre *aller* et *être* qui en soit responsable. Mais non, il s'agit uniquement de l'emploi du **passé composé** avec été pour aller qui choquât (certains), alors qu'au passé simple et au subjonctif imparfait il s'agît d'un usage littéraire à souhait (« *Il oublia de dîner et fut à Médrano* », Mauriac ; « *Il était temps que chacun fût se coucher.* »). Avec *s'en aller*, on n'a que les formes littéraires avec ces deux temps et *être*.

---

Au *LBU* (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, ed. *Duculot*, 14<sup>e</sup>, § 833 b, d'où sont tirées les citations et idées), on note le reproche qu'adressait *Voltaire* à *Corneille* d'avoir employé « *il fut jusques à Rome implorer le sénat* », et c'est sur cette critique que se fonde en bonne partie l'idée que être pour aller était inadéquat, malgré les classiques (« *Et nous fusmes coucher* », Molière). On répond :

> Je fus le chercher dans sa retraite. (Voltaire)

On peut même se poser des questions sur l'étiquette de *familier* dont on affuble trop souvent l'usage au passé composé :

> Autrefois je barbouillais du papier avec mes filles, Atala, Blanca,
>   Cymodocée, chimères qui ont été cherché ailleurs la jeunesse.
>   (Châteaubriand)

Enfin, avec les emplois *au figuré*, *avoir été* est bien plus largement représenté, au point de rendre certains emplois avec *aller* moins naturels : « *tout serait donc bien allé sans la nouvelle dame Barbaz* » (Ramuz).

---

*Réponse* : Oui, on peut aussi utiliser « j'ai été à Paris » pour « je suis allé à Paris ». On motivera son choix.