# “Y” or “le/la” as a pronoun to replace a place?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, indications-de-lieu

If I'm asking someone "Have you been there?" for example, say asking about Venice, would it be:

> Tu l'as visité ?

or:

> Tu y as visité ?

I'm guessing both are wrong, but yeah. Not sure how to replace "there" in this sort of question.

Comment: Note that in some regions (around Lyon, but maybe elsewhere too), using "y" in place of "le/la" in very common, for example saying "t'y as fait?" instead of "tu l'as fait?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the examples you gave, the first one is correct but can sound strange in French. We usually say "Tu y es allé?" or "tu as déjà été à Venise"?

The difference between "j'ai été" and "je suis allé" is tricky. I wrote an article about that if you want to know more about [this rule](http://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/jai-ete-ou-je-suis-alle-orthographe).

Comment: Le Ngrams proposé dans l'article est complètement biaisé. « J'ai été » c'est aussi le début de n'importe quel passé composé à la voix passive, ou d'une utilisation attributive du verbe *être* des plus banales. « Je suis allé » peut aussi être suivi d'un verbe pour un tout autre résultat. Mais comprenez-moi bien, je ne dis pas que « J'ai été quelque part » n'est pas utilisé, au contraire. Le style informel des questions proposés m'a fait penser à « Tu y as été ? » en premier. Pour ce qui est de la langue formelle, ce qui est sûr c'est qu'on ne peut rien déduire de ce Ngrams.

Comment: « T'as déjà visité Venise ? », or « T'y as déjà été ? » also sound good :)

Comment: Voir aussi [ceci](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/17727).

Answer (score 0):

"tu as déjà été à Venise"? signifie es-tu déjà allé à Venise, puisqu'il s'agit d'une question. Et dans ce cas, les deux se disent.
Sans point d'interrogation, il s'agirait d'une affirmation et on ne pourrait pas dire: ''As-tu déjà été à Venise''. Puisque, en Français la forme interrogative nécessite que l'on inverse le sujet et le verbe.
Pour valider la phrase: ''Tu y es allé ! '' il faut d'abord avoir ''situé'' le lieu de l'action ( en l'occurrence, aller) ! Le ''Y'' évite de faire une répétion comme : Tu connais Paris ? J'y suis déjà allé !