# « Je suis allé » et « J'ai été » : Différents ou non ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, auxiliaires

Je feuilletais la partie de conjugaison dans le livre 
[La Nouvelle Grammaire du Français, Larousse](https://www.priceminister.com/offer/buy/2401894190/la-nouvelle-grammaire-du-francais.html?t=180122&gclid=Cj0KCQjw9LPYBRDSARIsAHL7J5naJQHR0wO68VmOwfjNC0dHXlduosn8mQOcApvvBqIdMAbPgHLSvvIaAvqREALw_wcB&bbaid=3156692125&sort=0&xtatc=PUB-%5Bggp%5D-%5BLivres%5D-%5BLitterature%5D-%5B2401894190%5D-%5Boccasion%5D-%5BAmmareal%20-%20Occasion%5D&ptnrid=sls70z4do_dc%7Cpcrid%7C62178385283%7Cpkw%7C%7Cpmt%7C)

Parlant du verbe aller, les auteurs affirment (passage tiré du livre):

> Aux temps composés, on dit **je suis allé** (indiquant je crois que ce verbe se
>   conjugue avec être comme auxiliaire) ou **j'ai été**.

Je n'arrive pas à comprendre cette affirmation.
Les auteurs indiquent que le sens de la phrase

> **Je suis allé au cinéma**

et celui de la phrase

> **J'ai été au cinéma**

coïncident, non ?

C'est la première fois que j'ai vu une telle chose. Je souhaite trouver plus d'informations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qu'est-ce qui est le plus commun: « j'ai été à Paris » ou « je suis allé à Paris » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8245/quest-ce-qui-est-le-plus-commun-jai-%c3%a9t%c3%a9-%c3%a0-paris-ou-je-suis-all%c3%a9-%c3%a0-paris)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les verbes *être* et *aller* ne signifient pas la même chose. Il y a donc une nuance entre les deux phrases même si, à priori, si on a été quelque part, c'est qu'on y est allé auparavant.

> Je suis allé au cinéma

et

> J'ai été au cinéma

sont ici interchangeables.

*Aller* implique cependant un mouvement alors qu'*être* est statique, ce qui fait qu'en fonction du contexte, l'un ou l'autre peut être préférable, voire obligatoire; ex:

> Je suis allé au cinéma avec mes enfants, mais c'était complet alors on a été/on est allé à la fête foraine.
>
> J'ai été au cinéma avec mon ami que j'ai retrouvé là bas. (On y a été ensemble, mais on y est allés séparément).

On ne dit pas  :

> <s>Je suis allé deux fois en retard à l'école.</s>

mais

> J'ai été deux fois en retard à l'école.

de même, on dit :

> Je suis allé au cinéma en taxi.

et on est pas censé dire :

> <s>J'ai été au cinéma en taxi.</s>

mais on le fait quand même souvent en français relâché.

En français écrit, on peut constater que la tendance est d'utiliser *être allé* plutôt qu'*avoir été*, probablement en partie par hypercorrection, *avoir été* ayant mauvaise presse chez certains puristes.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

C'est exactement ce que ce passage indique, oui: dans la langue courante, les temps composés d'*aller* sont peu utilisés et les paradigmes d'autres verbes sont empruntés pour les remplacer.

Plus le registre de langue est élevé, plus *être allé* est utilisé, et dans la langue soutenue, c'est la seule option à recommander (l'usage d'*avoir été* étant victime de l'opprobre prescriptiviste).

Ce qui semble avoir déclenché le déclin d'*être allé*, c'est que les conditions de vérité de "je suis allé au cinéma" et "j'ai été cinéma" sont quasi-identiques. La seule hypothèse qui permettrait à "j'ai été cinéma" d'être vrai mais pas à "je suis allé au cinéma" est celle dans laquelle l'auteur de la phrase s'est toujours trouvé au cinéma sans jamais le quitter.

Le fait qu'*être*, bien que très fréquent, est plus fréquemment un auxiliaire ou un verbe copule que verbe principal a sans doute facilité le processus en réduisant les cas d'ambigüité possibles.

De là, *avoir été* s'est immiscé dans d'autres usages d'*aller*:

> Il est allé courir -> il a été courir
>
> Vous êtes allé de Paris à Bruxelles à vélo? -> Vous avez été de Paris à Bruxelles en vélo?

Mais ce remplacement va plus loin. Là où l'usage d'*avoir été* est critiqué par les puristes dans les deux exemples précédents, il est obligatoire pour les temps composé de l'expression "ça va": Pour prendre des nouvelles de quelqu'un, on va toujours demander "ça a été, tes vacances?" et jamais "c'est allé, tes vacances?" (La langue soutenue préfèrera *se passer* dans ce contexte: "Comment se sont passé tes vacances?")

*S'en être allé* tend à être évité également dans les temps composés de *s'en aller*, mais ce sont des verbes synonymes qui sont recruté plutôt qu'*avoir été*:

> Je m'en suis allé à minuit -> Je suis parti à minuit
>
> Ils s'en sont allés en courant -> Ils se sont barrés en courant

Ce phénomène est loin d'être limité au français, l'exemple le plus proche étant l'espagnol, où le passé simple d'*ir* et de *ser* est identique: fui, fuiste, etc.