# On avait été chercher

Tags: grammaire, infinitif, passé-composé, passif

*Je cherche* l'explication de la construction grammaticale utilisée dans la phrase suivante :

```
On avait été chercher une pâtisserie à Yvetot.
```

(Attribué à Flaubert.)

Je dirais *On avait cherché une pâtisserie à Yvetot.* J'ai pensé à une faute d'orthographe dans *On avait été cherché une pâtisserie à Yvetot.*, mais ça ne fait pas beaucoup de sens non plus. Par contre, la phrase semble correcte en anglais :
*We were to look for a cake in Yvetot.* (plus literallement *We had been to look for a cake in Yvetot.*), même si ça a un sens d'obligation.

[Link to the original poster](https://images.app.goo.gl/CZauaneqQ2ja3FPy6)

Comment: A ce propos, certains connaissent peut-être un épisode fameux du sapeur Camember : pour indiquer que le gardien est parti manger, le sapeur (à l'orthographe approximative) écrit "le gardien a été mangé", provoquant la panique chez les passants, croyant qu'il a été dévoré par une bête sauvage!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La citation exacte est :

> On **avait été chercher** un pâtissier à Yvetot, pour les tourtes et les nougats.

Elle est équivalente<sup>1</sup> à :

> On **était allés chercher** un pâtissier à Yvetot, pour les tourtes et les nougats.

et signifie littéralement :

> *We had been to pick up a pastry chef in Yvetot [...]*

ou (extrait de la traduction de Geoffrey Wall, la plus proche du sens original de la forme « avoir été chercher ») :

> *[...] had brought in a pastry-cook from Yvetot [...]*

Sans l’auxiliaire *être*, la phrase « On avait cherché un pâtissier à Yvetot » aurait signifié quelque chose comme *We looked for a pastry chef in Yvetot* mais sans indication sur le succès de l'opération.

---

Voici ce que donne la phrase en question dans quelques traductions anglaises de Madame Bovary :

1. *A confectioner of Yvetot had been intrusted with the tarts and sweets.* Eleanor Marx-Aveling
2. *They had found a patissier from Yvetot to make the tarts and the nougat.* Christopher Moncrieff
3. *They had gone to Yvetot to find a baker for the pastry and the nougats.* Mildred Marmur
4. *They had brought in a pastry-cook from Yvetot for the tarts and the cakes.* Geoffrey Wall
5. *A pastry cook had been imported from Yvetot for the tarts and almond cakes.* ?
6. *The pies and cakes had been ordered from a caterer in Yvetot.* Francis Steegmuller

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Cette équivalence existe depuis « toujours » en français mais elle est considérée comme populaire par des grammaires prescriptives. Voir aussi [« Je suis allé » et « J'ai été » : Différents ou non ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30379)</sub>

Comment: Merci pour la clarification. Je l'avais vu sur une affiche dans la boulangerie yvtotaise - j'ai ajouté un lien. Voyant le contexte, ce n'est pas surprenant, que la citation est inexacte.

Comment: Indeed, 'been' here is the equivalent of 'gone'. 'We had been/gone to look for.'

Comment: @LukeSawczak *Chercher* a plusieurs sens. Dans le contexte du récit, ils sont allés chercher signifie qu'ils ont choisi et ramené un pâtissier plutôt qu'ils en ont recherché un. C'est pour ça que j'ai mis *pick-up* et pas *look for*.

Comment: @jlliagre True enough.

Comment: On était allés chercher??

Comment: @Lambie Please elaborate.

Comment: "on" is a third person singular pronoun. It doesn't agree with anything.

Comment: @Lambie There is always an agreement in French. An indefinite *on* agrees with the masculine singular so I agree I could have used the prescriptive *on était allé chercher*. However, I prefer the more logical plural agreement that assumes this *on* has the value of a *nous* (*nous étions **allés** chercher un pâtissier...*)

Comment: @jlliagre Excuse me but I have never seen an "on" pronoun being anything other than third person singular. Using the singular is not "prescriptive" since this is "langage populaire" and not formal French. "on" is not "nous" per se. The meaning is nous but using "allés" here with "on" is very weird.

Comment: @Lambie Of course, it is a third person singular. I wrote *on était*, not *on sommes*. I'm talking about the past participle agreement. The original sentence was already using an informal tone so there is no reason to make it more formal than it was.

Comment: You wrote this in your answer:  **On était allés chercher**, *Please stop derailing my comments. You do not have to agree with them but you misstate them a lot*. I wonder why....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135139/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-lambie).

Answer (score 1):

La phrase vient du texte suivant :

> On avait été chercher un pâtissier à Yvetot pour les tourtes et les nougats. Comme il débutait dans le pays, il avait soigné les choses ; et il apporta, lui-même, au dessert, une pièce ...

La forme est grammaticalement correcte. Cette phrase peut s'interpréter comme une ellipse de "On avait été *envoyé* chercher un pâtissier (...)", qu'on pourrait reformuler comme "On avait été envoyé à la recherche d'un pâtissier". L'ellipse du verbe permet de mettre l'emphase sur la recherche plutôt que l'envoi.

Dans ce contexte, le verbe "chercher" est utilisé comme complément du sujet "on" (certainement un coursier), pour décrire son action, et non comme verbe de la phrase. Le verbe de la phrase serait "envoyer", conjugué au plus-que-parfait surcomposé de l'indicatif. Il s'agit d'une forme qui permet d'exprimer l'antériorité *progressive* de l'action par rapport au plus-que-parfait, et permet de reconstituer, avec précision, la chronologie des événements.

- le pâtissier débute son activité dans le pays
- quelqu'un envoie "on" chercher un pâtissier
- le pâtissier soigne les choses
- le pâtissier apporte la pièce lui-même

Note: l'ellipse du verbe "envoyer" pourrait être le point de départ d'une réflexion intéressante sur l'invisibilisation des rapports de domination dans le langage, et donc la pensée.